# Export HTML to Excel Avoid Removing Leading

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel

```
public void MssHtmlToMSExcel(string ssInnerHTML, string ssFileName, out string ssError)
        {

            ssError = "";
            try
            {
                ssFileName = ssFileName == "" ? "ExportedExcel" : ssFileName;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + ssFileName.Trim() + ".xls");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ssInnerHTML);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                ssError = "";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ssError = e.Message;
            }
        } // MssHtmlToMSExcel
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Excel files aren't HTML. They're ZIP packages containing XML files. What you try to do is an ugly hack, sending an HTML file with a fake extension and the wrong content type. Excel won't be fooled and will try to *import* that file as an actual HTML file.

Comment: It's far, far easier to create a *real* Excel file using libraries like Epplus, NPOI, ClosedXML. Loading data into an Excel sheet can be as simple as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(listOfCustomers);`. There are a *lot* of SO answers that show how to create real Excel files

Comment: string style = @"<style>"
.text
{
mso-number-format:\@;
}
.td 
{
mso-number-format:'\@';
}
</style>";

After adding this style in .Net Code. Its Working fine

Answer (score 0):

string style = @"" .text { mso-number-format:@; } .td { mso-number-format:'@'; } ";
After adding this style in .Net Code. Its Working fine –